# is there such a thing as "match_sibling"? (as opposed to "match parent")

Tags: android, android-layout

is there a way to quickly and easily have a view match one of its siblings height or width? let's say I have this button and it has a sibling view element, in this case I don't care about width, but I need this button's height to match his sibling's

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="???"
        android:text="@string/muh_button"
        android:onClick="do_stuff"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use a `RelativeLayout` and the `layout_alignLeft` and `layout_alignRight` XML attributes to match width (the analogous properties `layout_alignTop` and `layout_alignBottom` would work for matching height). This only works if you want the views *aligned* though - otherwise, you'll have to use a dimension resource.

Here's an example with aligned Buttons and matching heights:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/muh_button"
        android:onClick="do_stuff"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button1"
        android:text="@string/muh_other_button"
        android:onClick="do_other_stuff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's an example with a dimension resource:

```
<SomeViewGroup
    ...>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:text="@string/muh_button"
        android:onClick="do_stuff"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:text="@string/muh_other_button"
        android:onClick="do_other_stuff"/>

</SomeViewGroup>
```

where the dimension `button_height` is defined in `dimens.xml`.